# Prove/Disprove: $ f_n(x) = \sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}} $ converges uniformly on $ [0,\infty) $. ( Proof Verification/Explanation )

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

**Prove/Disprove**: $ f_n(x) = \sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}}  $ converges uniformly on $ [0,\infty) $.

**Someone's attempt:** The sequence of functions does converge uniformly.
Let $ x \in [0,1) $. $ 1 \leq (1+x^n)^{1/n} \leq (2)^{1/n} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1 $  And from sandwich, $ f_n(x) \rightarrow 1  $ for $ x \in [0,1) $.

Let $ x \in [1,\infty) $, thus  $x=\sqrt[n]{x^{n}} \leqslant \sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}} \leqslant \sqrt[n]{x^{n}+x^{n}}=\sqrt[n]{2 x^{n}}=\sqrt[n]{2} \cdot x \rightarrow x$ And from sandwich, $ f_n(x) \rightarrow x  $ for $ x \in [1,\infty) $.

Hence, $ f_n $ converges pointwise to $f(x)= \begin{cases}1 & x \in[0,1) \\ x & x \in[1, \infty)\end{cases}$.

For $ [ 0,1) $:
$0 \leqslant \sup \left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|=\sup |\sqrt[n]{1+x}-1| \leqslant \sup |\sqrt[n]{2}-1| 
  \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \sup |1-1|=0$, hence by sandwich $\sup \left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$

For $[1,\infty) $:
$0 \leqslant \operatorname{sup}\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|=\sup \left|\sqrt[n]{1+x^{n}}-x\right| \leqslant \sup |\sqrt[n]{2} \cdot x-x| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \sup |x-x|=0$, hence by sandwich $\sup \left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

We saw $\sup \left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right| \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$ on $[0,\infty) $ hence there is uniform convergence on the interval. $ \square $

**Question**:
Is the attempt above correct? If not then why?
I've never seen one "breaks" the $ \sup $  for several different intervals ( $[ 0,1)$ , $ [1,\infty) $  )  and then takes the limit from inside of it ( for example: $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |\sqrt[n]{2}-1| =  \sup | \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2}-1| = \sup | 1-1| = 0  $   ).
I feel the above is very "hand" wavy and I could not justify the breaking of $\sup$ for different intervals and putting the limits inside the $ \sup $, but I would want someone elses opinion on this.

Related ( My question's about the above proof and not necessarily the solution as asked in the following questions ):
[Does $f_n(x) = \sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$ converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166648/does-f-nx-sqrtn1xn-converge-uniformly-on-0-infty)
[Uniform convergence of $f_n(x) =\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267045/uniform-convergence-of-f-nx-sqrtn1xn)
[Checking if $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}$ uniformly converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339833/checking-if-f-nx-sqrtn1xn-uniformly-converges)

Comment: What is the sup taken over? Think more about $\sup |\sqrt[n]{2}x - x|$ in particular.

Comment: The $\sup $ in general should be taken over $ [0,\infty) $ but in the attempted proof above, the $ \sup $ is separated over two different intervals, one on $ [0,1) $ and the other one $ [1,\infty) $ and I don't understand how such separation is possible.